# Can't get packages after installing Faience

Tags: installation, command-line

I installed the Faience theme (sudo apt-get install Faience) and it installed fine. Then I tried installing another package and it said this...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 faience : Depends: faenza but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please help :O!

Comment: First off, have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` as apt tells you?

Comment: This is most likely a problem during post-installation of a package that caused `apt-get` to abort. Removing the package is the only safe solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt-get remove faience`, or equivalently `sudo apt-get remove -f`. The fact that installing a package resulted in this situation is most likely a packaging problem that caused `apt-get` to abort during post-installation.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably because faience is made from faenza try donwloading them from [deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com/) rather than apt-get and placing them in your home folder under .icons or .themes (depends what they are) , if you are using gnome tweak tool/gnome shell you will possibly need the user theme extension specified.